# Translation of tangent vector $\mathbf{v}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{v}$

Tags: differential-geometry, transformation

$\newcommand{\Vec}{\mathbf{v}}\newcommand{\Pt}{\mathbf{p}}$This is an exercise in Barrett O'Neil's Elementary Differential Geometry 2nd Edition, p. 110 (Section 3.2)

---

If $T$ is a translation, show that for every tangent vector $\Vec$ the vector $T(\Vec)$ is parallel to $\Vec$.

---

My question is:

Isn't it the tangent map of $T$, not $T$ itself, which transform a tangent vector $\Vec$ at a point $\Pt$ to $T*(\Vec)$ at a point $T(\Pt)$?

(The star $*$ denotes tangent map in this textbook.)

I mean, I wonder whether it is possible to denote like $T(\Vec)$, which means that $T$ is directly applied to a tangent vector, not a point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A translation looks like $T(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x + \mathbf c$ for some fixed vector $\mathbf c$ (I assume everything's in $\Bbb R^3$, but it doesn't matter).

Any mapping $f$ induces an action on tangent vectors at $p$ by taking a curve $\boldsymbol\gamma(t)$ with $\boldsymbol\gamma(0)=p$ and $\boldsymbol\gamma'(0)=\mathbf v$ and finding the tangent vector to the curve $f(\boldsymbol\gamma)$ at $t=0$. Note that this will be a tangent vector at $f(p)$.

In our case, using $f=T$, for any such curve $\boldsymbol\gamma$, we have
$T(\boldsymbol\gamma(t)) = \boldsymbol\gamma(t)+\mathbf c$, so the derivative at $t=0$ is $\boldsymbol\gamma'(0) + \mathbf 0 = \mathbf v$. But we think of $\mathbf v$ as sitting (tangent) at $p$ and this new vector as sitting (tangent) at $T(p)$.

By the way, you should not write $T^*(\mathbf v)$. I do not know O'Neil's notation, but it certainly should not have an upper star.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Ted Shifrin. But in the answer you also needed more operations: you differentiated $T(\gamma(t))$ and put $t=0$ to get the new vector $\Vec$. What I want to ask is whether it is possible to denote like $T(\Vec)$ as in the problem, which means that $T$ is directly applied to a tangent vector, not a point.

Comment: How does O'Neil define what a map does to tangent vectors $\mathbf v$ at a point $p$? (I infer from your edit that he writes it $f_*(\mathbf v)$?)

Comment: Same as you did. $F*(\Vec_\Pt)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{d}{dt}F(\Pt+t\Vec)$

Comment: That's not right. But, ultimately, you do not apply $T$ to the vector. You apply $T_*$, the derivative, to the vector.

Comment: Oops, there is a typo... It should be $\lim_{t\to0}$

Comment: Maybe $\frac d{dt}\big|_{t=0} f(p+t\mathbf v)$. That's exactly what I did for you.

Comment: Oh, you're right ! My mistake, sorry. Anyway, now I'm more confident that O'Neill made a mistake...Thank you for your help !

Comment: Nah, he's calling the vector $\mathbf v$ sitting at $T(p)$ parallel to the vector $\mathbf v$ sitting at $p$. Can't argue with that.